# Send an email with the editable pdf placed in an iframe

Tags: ajax, laravel, email, pdf, iframe

I have a website built with Laravel and I need that the customer fills a editable PDF and send it to an specific address.

Instead of asking them to download it, fill it in local and then send it, I have created a new page in my site where I placed the editable PDF using an iframe.

Now, I would like to add a button that once the customer fills the PDF, it sends it automatically.

Does anybody know how to achieved this or is it not possible?

I am trying to do it using ajax, calling a method in my controller that will send the email using a template and with an attachment, but I don't know how to pass the PDF filled to it from the view(iframe).

Thank you in advance

Comment: You will have to store the pdf file first. In storage or temporary. After that you can simply attach() the file to your mailable/notification https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#attachments

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Christophvh. I already have the mailable part. Do you know how can I save the pdf filled from the iframe once I click the button?

Comment: There is an option in acrobat professional version that you can use, it can send the email as an XML I think.